# Pricing of Black-Scholes with dividend

Tags: black-scholes, mathematics, finance-mathematics

Consider the payoff $g(S_T)$ shown in the figure below. Consider Black-Scholes model for the price of a risky asset with $T = 1$, $r = .04$, and $\sigma = .02$ and dividends are paid quarterly with dividend yield $10\%$. Take $S_0 = 10$, $K_1 = 9$, and $K_2 = 11$. Find the Black-Scholes price, $\Delta$, $\Gamma$, $\rho$, and $\mathcal{V}$ of this option at time $t = 0$. Find $\Theta$ at time $t = 0$ without taking derivatives with respect to $S$.[image]

Solution: The payoff is, $$g(S_t) = (S_t - K_1)_{+} - 2(S_t - \frac{(K_1 + K_2)}{2})_{+} + (S_t - K_2)_{+}$$
The Black-Scholes formula with dividend gives \begin{align*}
V(t = 0,S) &= e^{-r\tau}\hat{\mathbb{E}}[g(\tilde{d}S_T)]\\
&= \tilde{d}\left(BS_{call}(\frac{K_1}{\tilde{d}}) - 2BS_{call}(\frac{K_1+K_2}{2\tilde{d}}) + BS_{call}(\frac{K_2}{\tilde{d}})\right)
\end{align*}
where $$\tilde{d} = \left(1 - \frac{d}{4} \right)^{4} = .9037$$
So, $$V(t = 0,S) = e^{-r\tau}\hat{\mathbb{E}}[g(\tilde{d}S_T)] = (.9037)((0) - 2(0) + (0)) \approx 0 $$
For the Greeks we have $$\Delta = \partial_S V(t = 0,S) = \tilde{d}\left[\Phi(d_1(\frac{K_1}{\tilde{d}})) + \Phi(d_1(\frac{K_1+K_2}{2\tilde{d}})) + N(d_1(\frac{K_2}{\tilde{d}})) \right] \approx 0$$
$$\Gamma = \partial_{SS}V(t = 0, S) = 0$$
$$\rho = \partial_r V(t = 0,S) = \left( e^{-rt}(\frac{K_1}{\tilde{d}})(t)\Phi(d_2) + e^{-rt}(\frac{K_1+K_2}{2\tilde{d}})(t)\Phi(d_2) + e^{-rt}(\frac{K_2}{\tilde{d}})(t)\Phi(d_2)\right) \approx 0$$
$$\mathcal{V} = (S\sqrt{t}\Phi(d_1) + S\sqrt{t}\Phi(d_1) + S\sqrt{t}\Phi(d_1)) \approx 0$$

Comment: Hint: read the question again; it is asking about price and greeks at t=0, not t=1.

Comment: @onlyvix.blogspot.com How is my solution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer, you don't include dividend.
I am sorry to say it is wrong.

Payoff function is
$$
g(S_T) = (S_T - K_1)_+  - 2(S_T - \frac{K_1+K_2}{2})_+ + (S_T - K_2)_+
$$

BS pricing formula with dividend gives
$$
V(t=0,S) = e^{-r}E(g(\tilde{d}S_T)) = \tilde{d} \left(BS_{call}\left(\frac{K_1}{\tilde{d}}\right) - 2BS_{call}\left(\frac{K_1+K_2}{2 \tilde{d}}\right) + BS_{call}\left(\frac{K_2}{\tilde{d}}\right)\right)
$$

Where
$$
\tilde{d} = (1-\frac{d}{4})^4 = 0.9037
$$
Plug in all numbers in your question, I get 0.3905 (double check it yourself).

As to the greeks,

$$
\Delta = \frac{\partial V(t=0,S)}{\partial S} = \tilde{d} \left[ N(d_1(K_1/\tilde{d})) - 2N(d_1((K_1+K_2)/(2\tilde{d}))) + N(d_1(K_2/\tilde{d})) \right]
$$
where $N$ is the normal c.d.f. and $d_1(K)=\frac{log(S/K)+(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma)\tau}{sigma\sqrt{\tau}}$.

Rest of the problem is pretty trivial because all greeks are just linear combination of original BS greeks. You just need change the strike price in the original BS greeks (I guess?). I won't go through all the calculation here.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Just so I understand I need to calculate the greeks gamma, rho, and vega as well?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind could you post the $BS_{call}$ formula for dividend.

Comment: As in $BS_{call}(K_1/\tilde{d})$ If you can show me the formula you are using that would be great as I am not sure how to apply your way with what I have in my notes

Comment: Calculate all greeks except $\Theta$, then you find $\Theta$ via BS PDE. Please refer to this note (http://www.econ-pol.unisi.it/fm10/greeksBS.pdf). $BS_{call}$ is exact the same as C in this note.You need to change strike price $K$ to $K/\tilde{d}$.

Comment: Sorry to abuse the notation $BS_{call}(K_1/\tilde{d})$. All I want to say is to change the strike price to $K/\tilde{d}$ in the BS call option pricing formula.

Comment: I got .3886 for the price

Comment: Also, your formula for $\Delta$ is different from what I have. Could you provide the formulas for the other greeks to your answer?

Comment: Also, using your $\Delta$ formula I get $0$

Comment: What you have for $\Delta$? BTW, there is a built-in function blsprice in matlab which you could use to check your answers.

Comment: Yes, using your $\delta$ formula the answer I get comes out as $0$. Also, could you provide the formulas for the greeks that I assume come from a text you have? That would be big help

Comment: You probably don't read the my answer carefully. I already post the reference in our discussion. Here is how I calculate the Delta using Matlab code

Comment: >> S=10;r=0.04;sigma=0.02;d=(1-0.1/4)^4;
>> K=9;
>> d1 = (log(S*d/K)+(r+0.5*sigma^2))/sigma;
>> normcdf(d1)

ans =

    0.9866

>> K=(9+11)/2;
>> d1 = (log(S*d/K)+(r+0.5*sigma^2))/sigma;
>> normcdf(d1)

ans =

    0.0011

>> K=11/2;
>> d1 = (log(S*d/K)+(r+0.5*sigma^2))/sigma;
>> normcdf(d1)

ans =

     1

>> 0.9866 - 2*0.0011 + 1

ans =

    1.9844

>> d*1.9844

ans =

    1.7933

>>

Comment: Can't you just add more to your solution? I want to see what you get for $\delta$? are you a native English speaker, not sure if you understand me

Comment: My Delta isn't zero. See my Matlab code in previous comment. Plus I am not a native English speaker but I understand you. This is not a problem of language. I doubt you understand math.

Comment: haha, just so you know I confirmed my solutions with my professor. Also, I am a PhD student in Financial Mathematics, I think it is safe to say I understand math.